# Источник данных. Не видит нового поля

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавил в объект новое поле, объект используется как источник данных для RDL отчета, приложение на winforms.
Использовал все доступные мне танцы с бубном: пробовал удалять/добавлять источник, пробовал закрывать/открывать VS и проект, даже ПК перезагрузил - не помогает!
Скрин приложил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Была у меня похожая проблема когда работал с базой данных Access расскажу что пробовал  1) попробуйте пересобрать проект (rebuild) 2) нажмите Refresh на RegistrRow 3)если два предыдущих не помогли удалите источники и Data binding

Comment: @OXYGEN помогло пересобрать! сделайте ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была у меня похожая проблема когда работал с базой данных Access расскажу что пробовал 1) попробуйте **пересобрать проект** (rebuild) 2) нажмите **Refresh** на RegistrRow 3)если два предыдущих не помогли **удалите источники и Data binding**